# Flutter Basics (write once, run anywhere?)

Tags: flutter

Hi stack overflow community,

I'm a novice programmer in high school and have never written an app for mobile devices before so please bear with me. If I was to write an app using Flutter, will I only be required to write the code once and then be able to distribute different versions of it (iOS, macOS, Windows, Linux, Android, etc)? Or will I need to make small changes for each version such as using XCode to create the iOS version and Android Studio for the Android version? I know this is such a basic question but I've spent a couple of hours looking this stuff up and I'm still confused. Any help would be nice.

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a product development environment, after writing the cross-platform code with Flutter, there are some need-to-do tasks related to Native environment.

In the case of Android, there are several cases when you'll need to touch the Native level such as config Firestore settings, Social authentication (Login with Facebook for example), changing the launch icons/ splash screen of the app or publishing to app store, etc

For iOS, the same case apply as well. So I suggest you start with small steps to develop the app first, then when running into something that seems impossible with just Flutter code, there are tutorials and SO to guide you through. It might seem overwhelmed at first, but we are all on a journey, so no need to rush it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should make small changes too. For eg when adding launcher icons and splash screen you have to edit the respective native folders. When distributing for ios you need to manually customize its Runner from xcode. There are many library that support either android only or ios only. In that case if you need that feature you have to make changes in native code like java ans swift.

Answer (score 0):

if you're creating your own native plugins, you will have unique code to write.  But if you're just using things out of pub, almost nothing will require change (unless you are publishing to the store).